# Merging [career] and [career-path] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two tags, which are similar:
[career](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and [career-path](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-path).

Should we join them?

If not, how should we make a clear distinction?

(I fail to see a clear distinction, neither in their descriptions, nor in the questions asked.)

EDIT:

Mods, could you make one a synonymous of another? I have not enough points to vote in these tags, and as of now it is one of the most annoying collision. BTW the funny thing is that the word `career` essentially means `path`.

Answer (score 1):

I proposed [career](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) to be a synonym of [career-path](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-path) about 6 months ago (along with a number of other proposals). They have been sitting in limbo at: https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

You can vote for existing proposals and propose new tag synonyms from the tag page. For example from [graduate-admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-admissions) there is a link to the [synonym page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/graduate-admissions/synonyms) for that tag. From there if you have enough rep within the tag you can either vote on the existing proposals or create a new proposal.

Comment: BTW: How to propose tag merging?

Comment: @PiotrMigdal I added a little more info to my answer.